# Connection String to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, vb6, sql-server-2012, connection-string

Currently I have a connection to server 2000 in a VB6 script using this...

```
Provider=sqloledb;Server=servername;Database=mydatabase;User Id=myid;Password=mypassword;OLE DB Services=-2;
```

And everything works fine with this as it always has. This has been running good for years.

I am now trying to connect to Sql Server 2012 from the same VB6 script using this:

```
Provider=sqloledb;Server=servername;Database=mydatabase;User Id=myid;Password=mypassword;
```

Everything works good here and I am able to write to the database just fine except while some of the scripts are running I get errors intermittently while the script is writing to the database.  This is the error:

> dbnetlib.connectionopen (connect()).]Sql server does not exist or
>   access denied.

I have to hit ok and then it keeps running.  Can I avoid this or fix my connection string?

I also tried to fix this using a new connection string of:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=servername;Database=mydatabase;User Id=myid;Password=mypassword;
```

But this gives me an error of:

> run time error 3706 provider can not be found it may not be properly
>   installed.

Can anyone please help me improve either one of the connection strings that I am trying to use above to connect to sql server 2012.

Comment: Does the log from SQL Server 2012 say something about a failed authentication?

Comment: No, there are no errors at all on the log.  Also no failed authentication on the logs.  Thanks!

Comment: Both connection strings are correct but the SQLNCLI11 OLE DB provider requires the SQL Server 2012 Native Client be installed on the client machine.  SQL Server Native Client is preferred over the legacy SQLOLEDB provider.  An intermittent "SQL Server does not exist or access denied" indicates an environmental issue (e.g. name resolution, non-responding server, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for the help.  The issue was I did not have it installed on the client machine.  As soon as I downloaded it everything worked.